# Issue with Billing Account associated with Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Good morning. I had a problem changing my debit card to Google Play and I found that there were two subscriptions to the Goggle Cloud Platform for two projects that I didn't even know existed connected with a non-existent debit card (closed). Now I am trying to contact with support and I am only allowed the phone support which is difficult for me. Is there any way to know what these projects are? Cancel and stop any charges; finally to delete google cloud platform because I don’t even know how it works. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest you reach out to the [Sales department](https://cloud.google.com/contact). You may also use the [GCP Billing Troubleshooter](https://support.google.com/cloud/troubleshooter/7279311?hl=en&ref_topic=6288636). Regarding the projects you want to shutdown, [follow the instructions](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects) on how to do this through the [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com).